# refresh table without refreshing page using ajax Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

i am using ajax for updating page without refreshing in Django
i want to update table but i am not using api in my views.py can i want refresh only the table

**script**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',// type of the form 
    data: $('#tableid').serialize(), // all the  form name 
    success: function (data) {
        return data // i don't want all return data i want only table data it should refresh
    }   
});
```

Comment: You need to add a new API or get the relevant parts out from your response data. It is hard to answer that based on the information provided in the question. Please consider adding some more information like what is returned by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this bro take the new table data and innerHTML in old table data

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: $('#tableid').serialize(),  
    success: function (data) {
        var old_tabel_data = document.getElementById('tableid'); // old table 
        var htmlObject = $(data); 
        var new_table_data =htmlObject.find("#tableid").html(); // new table
        old_table_data.innerHTML=new_table_data;
    }   
});
```